# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'barcodeScanner'

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using barcodescanner.js to scan the qr code. I have the CaptureActivity android library downloaded and attached to my project

But when I call the following code

```
window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(scannerSuccess, scannerFailure);
```

Its giving me an error that

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'barcodeScanner' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/html/scan.html:83
```

It was working fine yesterday but giving me an error today. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you referencing the barcode scanner JS file correctly? Did you recently upgrade the version of PG you are using?

Comment: It was working fine yesterday with same configuration. The PG version i m using is cordova-1.7.0.js

Comment: Is you barcodescanner.js referencing PhoneGap.exec or Cordoava.exec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the index.html, are you referencing the right javascript? In my case I had this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
```

When I should have written this (cordova-xxx instead of phonegap-xxx):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
```

Check in your assets folder and reference the right one. This solved my problem.